# Windows Phone Ad Blocking

Tags: windows-10-mobile

iPhone has a "built in" ad blocking framework now, so apps can be built to facilitate...

Android has apps that ad block, without root ([AdBlock Plus](https://adblockplus.org/en/android-install)), with root ([Ad-Away, FDroid](https://f-droid.org/repository/browse/?fdid=org.adaway)) or with a special browser ([AdBlock Browser](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=org.adblockplus.browser)) (just a few examples).

Ad Blocking is import for security, screen real-estate, bandwidth, etc

I'm considering jumping unto the Windows Phone bandwagon when the Nokia 950/950 XL gets released next month...

Of a few questions regarding Windows 10 that I have: Are there apps? Is there a need to "Jailbreak"/"root"? Or will AdBlock on the Windows Phone involve using a proxy of some sort?

In Short: What are the Ad Block options in Windows 10? Hosts file editing?

Comment: Adblockers will affect the revenue to the developers, advertisers and a whole lot of ad industries, which inturn will affect quality of apps coming into market, and also with very less of free apps and more paid apps.

Comment: @franklins And not using an Ad Blocker affects my wallet (Phone Data isn't free or unlimited), phone battery life, page load times, security vectors, trackers watching my every move, etc... As a programmer, I understand that ads help give me "free" websites. I also understand that free content isn't "free". I'll pay a few bucks to remove ads from aps I use. Don't act like Ads are the victims of heartless pirates - there are plenty of problems with them and plenty of reasons to block them.

Answer (score 7):

There are currently no content blocking APIs available for developer and therefore no add blocker apps in the store. It doesn't seem like this is going to change with Windows 10 Mobile, but with Apple now supporting this it might also come a bit further down the road.

You should take a look at https://windowsphone.uservoice.com and perhaps post this as a suggestion there.

As for unofficial ways, you can check out sites like xda developers if they found a solution to this, but I'm not aware of any.

Comment: Microsoft Edge will be able to have extensions, like Google Chrome.  Will this not be added to the mobile version then?

Comment: Hrm... I wonder if its going to come down to Hosts file, like on Windows, or custom DNS server or proxy

Comment: I wouldn't expect extensions to work on the mobile version of Edge - there is no official info yet, though. Mobile versions of chrome don't either, right?

Answer (score 0):

There's one adblocker available for interop unloacked windows phone on 8.1 as well as 10.

I havent used it and am not sure how it works but refer to this [**link**](http://winphonehub.org/interop-adblocker-for-windows-phone-8-1-windows-10-mobile/) or this [**one**](http://forum.xda-developers.com/windows-phone-8/development/xap-adblocker-windows-phone-8-x-t3178203).